# Cloudinary uploading images twice

Tags: next.js

I have following code in my project.  For some reason, when this component is called using, `{file && <SnapImage snap={file} setSnap={setSnap} />},` from another component, it upload the image twice.  I've tried multiple different options but keeps uploading the image twice.  Please help!
(I've changed folder name and cloudname with **********)

```
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { LoadingLine } from './Loading';

export default function SnapImages({ snap, setSnap }) {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [imageUploaded, setImageUploaded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (snap && !imageUploaded) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', snap);
            formData.append('upload_preset', '********');
            fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/********/image/upload/', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    setSnap(data.secure_url);
                    console.log(data.secure_url);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    setImageUploaded(true);
                })
                .catch((error) => console.log('Error', error));
        };
    }, [snap, setSnap, isLoading]);

    if (isLoading) return (<LoadingLine />);

    return (
        <>
            Thumbnail upload completed
        </>
    );
}
```

Tried to upload images via cloudinary but keeps uploading image twice.
expecting it to just upload image once.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using React.js and every component is mounted/called twice
If you want to upload any image i recommend you make a component and use submit button to upload an image

Comment: Thanks! created another submit button and solved the issue!